# Stacked Bar Chart from two columns with one containing duplicates

Tags: google-sheets

I have two columns, A and B, with A containing some duplicates. Can I, in Google Sheets, create a stacked bar chart from these, such that the duplicates are a new stack on top of the others?

Data could be:

```
Date       | Duration
-----------+---------
01/01/2017 |    1 min
01/02/2017 |    2 min
01/02/2017 |    1 min
01/03/2017 |    1 min
```

where I would then like three bars, one for each unique date, with 1, 3, and 1 minutes respectively, with the second one being two bars stacked.

---

Edit: It seems, that I can do this by editing the data into:

```
Date       | Duration |
-----------+----------+------
01/01/2017 |    1 min |
01/02/2017 |    2 min | 2 min
01/03/2017 |    1 min |
```

but then I would have to add a new column for for each duplicate. There could potentially be many (*although in my case not that many*). With this I can make a chart over the data from A1:C4 and Google Sheets will pick up the first column as key and the two as the stacked columns. Again, it works, but I would rather have a solution for the original problem without modifying the data.

An example of what I would like can be seen here: [image: Stacked bar chart]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I ended up modifying @anonymous' answer a bit.

I couldn't get the `ARRAYFORMULA` with two `{{...}}` to work, so instead I did the following:

- In `Sheet2` I entered into `A1`:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({"Date", "Duration" & TRANSPOSE(ROW(INDIRECT("Sheet1!A1:A" & MAXA(COUNTIF(Sheet1!A2:A100, Sheet1!A2:A100)))))})`

- This gives the headers for the table. The entry that has the most duplicates dictates how many headers there is going to be.
- In `A2` I wrote the other half of @anonymous' original formula:

`=ARRAYFORMULA({UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A999), SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A999)=TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!A2:A999), TRANSPOSE(Sheet1!C2:C999), "")),"",1000)), " ")})`

- This then inputs all the data, with all the duplicates in each their own cell. The problem with @anonymous' formula, was that it gave a lot of blank spaces, which in turn required a separate cell for each space. With the query obtaining 1000 blank cells, it would require 1000 columns, which the sheet didn't have, so it gave an error.
- The above works beautifully and I can now, in `Sheet1` input a stacked column chart from `Sheet2`, which in turn is pulling data from `Sheet1`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question edit and clarification,

I do not think there's any other way to make a stacked column chart without reordering the data. After extracting numbers using

```
   =ARRAYFORMULA(--REGEXEXTRACT(B2:B7,"\d+"))
```

A900:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({{"Date","Dopple"&char(10)&"Ganger"& transpose(ROW(indirect("A1:A"&1+MAXA(COUNTIF(A2:A15,A2:A15)))))};{UNIQUE(A2:A15),(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(UNIQUE(A2:A15)=TRANSPOSE(A2:A15), transpose(B2:B15)&"™","")),,500)),"™"))}})
```

A2:A15 will be date. And B2:B15 will be Duration

Select A900:Z1000 and create a stacked Column chart. Note that, If there aren't sufficient number of Duplicates, Such items will not be stacked.

Comment: It does work for smaller datasets, but I am not allowed to use more than A2:A26 for this. I believe that it might be checking the number of columns available? Even though I do not have 26 duplicates it gives me an error "In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.".

Comment: Try changing `500` to `50000` or more, if needed.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. You can. Select your data> Insert Chart> Stacked Bar chart. You will have what you require as long as your data is formatted properly.

**Formatting requirements:**

- Column A and B should be numbers. If your data is aligned right, then they all are numbers.

If not,

- Format Column A as Date. They should automatically be aligned right.
- Extract numbers from column B.

  ```
     =ARRAYFORMULA(--REGEXEXTRACT(B1:B4,"\d+"))
  ```

This will remove all "min" and other unnecessary and useless words and give a number back. Copy this and `paste values only` over the original data.

Now create a chart over this data.

EDIT:

If the above doesn't work, you need to re-order the data. Try this:

```
 =QUERY(A1:B5,"Select A,Sum(B) group by A")
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. It doesn't stack properly. See this image for an example: http://i.imgur.com/nXZygUb.png

Comment: That is strange. I am not able to reproduce this. Could you just select the data without the headers (date and duration) and add chart?    If nothing works, Use `QUERY`:See my edit.

Comment: That would still just get me the sum and not have them stacked.